# How do I get these divs to stack vertically?

Tags: html, css

I know that similar questions have been asked before but I've tried all the solutions I could find (which involve position:relative on the outer div and position: absolute on the inner divs) but I can't for the life of me get the red div to align underneath the green one rather than stacking on top of it.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="outer_div">
         <div id="title_div">
         </div>

        <div id="main_div">
        </div>
    </div>
</body/>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#outer_div {

    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
}    

#title_div {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    display: block;
}

#main_div {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
}
```

[Here's the jsFiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/kFaVe/)

Thanks!

Comment: divs are block elements so flow naturally top to bottom - why do you need to change their default positioning? red and green start at 0,0 so what do you expect? remove everything but color style and maybe height and width and see what happens

Comment: I've updated your jsfiddle with a possible solution (http://jsfiddle.net/denisonluz/kFaVe/1/)

Comment: @jenson-button-event, you're exactly right. That'll teach me for coding late, complicating the problem then trying to abstract it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

To get the red div to display beneath the green div, do the following

1. Remove `"position: absolute;"` from `#main_div` and `#title_div`
2. Add `"float: left;"` to `#main_div` and `#title_div`

This will cause each div to pull itself as far left as possible. If it won't fit both of them side by side, the second one automatically is pushed below the first.

Comment: You really don't need to do the extra floats. Floats are used to get things side by side, which is the opposite of what you want. But yes, this is the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have the same absolute top position for both the inner divs.  There are many ways to change this including allows natural ordering of divs, changing the top position etc.